# Direct2d Is that possible to draw on window by monitor size regardless of window size?

Tags: winapi, directx, directx-11, direct2d

I have directx window which renders with Direct2D. My issue when window resized drawn 2D content is scaled by window size since renderTarget is resized. I do not want to use a CHILD WINDOW which is equal to monitor size. I should draw on same window. I found **HwndRenderTarget** which many help to render 2D regardless of window size change. I am not sure if that is used for that.

My 2D render target:

```
    D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS options2d;
options2d.debugLevel = D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_NONE;
result = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE::D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_MULTI_THREADED, options2d, &m_factory2d);

m_screenSize.x = screenWidth; m_screenSize.y = screenHeight;

if (FAILED(result))
{
    return false;
}

// set up the D2D render target using the back buffer

m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_dxgiBackbuffer));

D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES props = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT, D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED));

m_factory2d->CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget(m_dxgiBackbuffer, props, &m_d2dRenderTarget);
```

HWND render target:

```
    RECT rc;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);

D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES RTprops = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties();
D2D1_HWND_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES RT_hWndProps = D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hwnd, size,D2D1_PRESENT_OPTIONS::D2D1_PRESENT_OPTIONS_IMMEDIATELY);
result = m_factory2d->CreateHwndRenderTarget(RTprops, RT_hWndProps, &m_d2dHwndRenderTarget);
```

and:

```
void D2DClass::TryRenderHWNDText() {
        static const WCHAR sc_helloWorld[] = L"Hello, World!";

        // Retrieve the size of the render target.
        D2D1_SIZE_F renderTargetSize = m_d2dHwndRenderTarget->GetSize();

        m_d2dHwndRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
        m_d2dHwndRenderTarget->Clear(ColorF(ColorF::Red));

        m_d2dHwndRenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());
        m_whiteBrush->SetColor(ColorF(ColorF::Orange));
        if(textFormat){
        m_d2dHwndRenderTarget->DrawTextW(
            sc_helloWorld,
            ARRAYSIZE(sc_helloWorld) - 1,
            textFormat,
            D2D1::RectF(0, 0, renderTargetSize.width, renderTargetSize.height),
            m_whiteBrush
        );
        }
        m_d2dHwndRenderTarget->EndDraw();
}
```

in render loop:

```
bool GraphicsClass::Render()
{
    m_Direct3D->BeginScene(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    /*RENDER 2D renderTarget NOT hwndTarget and 3D target*/
    m_Direct3D->EndScene();

    m_Direct2D->TryRenderHWNDText();

}
```

BeginScene:

```
void D3DClass::BeginScene(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha)
{
    float color[4];


    // Setup the color to clear the buffer to.
    color[0] = red;
    color[1] = green;
    color[2] = blue;
    color[3] = alpha;

    // Clear the back buffer.

    m_deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(m_renderTargetView, color);

    // Clear the depth buffer.
    m_deviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);

    return;
}
```

End Scene:

```
void D3DClass::EndScene()
{
    // Present the back buffer to the screen since rendering is complete.
    if (m_vsync_enabled)
    {
        // Lock to screen refresh rate.
        m_swapChain->Present(1, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        // Present as fast as possible.
        m_swapChain->Present(0, 0);
    }

    return;
}
```

I see 2D and 3D but no HWNDrenderTarget. What am I missing here ?
Is there any solution for my purpose ?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: If you already have a swapchain and a dxgi render target, why do you need a hwnd render target?

Comment: @Simon Mourier If I resize my window all 2D content becomes scaled too I want to keep their scale based on monitor scale. I want to render 2D content based on of monitor size not the client area. If that is possible to do it with dxgi render target I want to know.

Comment: You only need one render target. Just draw on your m_d2dRenderTarget that's already mapped on the swapchain.

Comment: Can I use m_swapChain->ResizeBuffers(); - set it to screen size when window resized maybe ???

Comment: yes, you can do that.

Comment: @GomiOdabaşıoğlu Has this issue been solved?

Comment: @Rita Han For my case it does not support resizing like this. (For DXGI Surface Render Target) To accomplish this I have to release the D3Device but this will cause performance issue. In order to prevent this issue Microsoft docs advice to keep  2D Resources alive during re-creation process and re-use them. This solves the mystery for me. However, I have many many things to do and this will be the last thing to work on.

Comment: @Rita Han I think should set D3D11_VIEWPORT by GetDeviceContext()->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport); then set camera frustum for 3D drawing for 2D thats not needed. This will not need to release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

**NOTE:** *this solution is for condition you have a borderless child window which has the size of monitor.*

You should modify viewport size and screen aspect of your program,
Just define somewhere D3D11_VIEWPORT. Then set width(Parent window width),height(Parent window height),SCREEN_NEAR(0.1),SCREEN_DEPTH(1000) and screenAspect.

Here is result:

```
void SystemClass::UpdateFrame() {

    if (ApplicationHandle->m_Graphics) {

            GetClientRect(ApplicationHandle->m_hwndOWNER, &clientRect);
            int w = ApplicationHandle->ClientSize.x = RECTWIDTH(clientRect);
            int h = ApplicationHandle->ClientSize.y = RECTHEIGHT(clientRect);
    
            ApplicationHandle->m_Graphics->clientSize = { w, h };
    
    
            viewport.Width = RECTWIDTH(clientRect);
            viewport.Height = RECTHEIGHT(clientRect);
    
            ApplicationHandle->m_Graphics->m_Direct3D->GetDeviceContext()->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);
    
            float fieldOfView = 3.141592654f / 4.0f;
            float screenAspect = (float)RECTWIDTH(clientRect) / (float)RECTHEIGHT(clientRect);
    
            ApplicationHandle->m_Graphics->m_Direct3D->m_projectionMatrix = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(fieldOfView, screenAspect, SCREEN_NEAR, SCREEN_DEPTH);
    
            ApplicationHandle->m_Graphics->Frame();
            DXRGN = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, w, h);
            SetWindowRgn(ApplicationHandle->m_hwnd, DXRGN, 0);
        }
    }
```

Just call the void above to get it work in messages. To prevent conflict between messages *WM_SIZING*, *WM_SIZE* and *WM_MOVE* put a bool *Is_WM_SIZING* and allow *UpdateFrame()* only if this is false when *WM_SIZE* and *WM_MOVE* message produced. Set this value in WM_EXITSIZEMOVE message to false and after call *UpdateFrame()* too. This will prevent some type of rendering issue depending on your present(...) call.

Additional Operation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowrgn

Sometimes, if you resize your window too fast from the left, top-left, bottom-left and top this produces serious artifacts and overflow to right or bottom. Microsoft docs says SetWindowRgn prevents drawing outside of its content this made my program better.

```
HRGN hrgn; //DEFINE SOMEWHERE OUTSIDE
/*----*/
hrgn = CreateRectRgn(0,0,windowWidth,windowHeight);
SetWindowRgn(ApplicationHandle->m_hwnd, hrgn,0); //last parameter should be 0
```